# How to calculate the computing power gap of different CPUs

Tags: cpu

I want to compare the performance gap between the two machines, the main consideration here is memory and CPU. For example, the theoretical calculation peak of the CPU. Theoretical CPU peak = main frequency × number of cores × CPU double-precision floating-point number operations per clock cycle. But this is the theoretical peak, which is very different from the actual result.And how to calculate the impact of memory size on CPUs.

The accuracy requirements here are not very high, only a rough accuracy is required, which is smaller than the theoretical peak error (the theoretical peak error is large and memory is not involved). The program is known and can be obtained from test information (such as time, space complexity, etc.)

Comment: If the software does not need all the memory, more memory does not help. If the software can't take advantage of more core, more cores don't help. And now, for three curve balls: 1. storage performance, in particular considering virtual memory. 2. using a GPU means less work for the CPU. 3. anything network. Edit: start from what do you need the metric for, and whether or not a metric is good for that, and worry less about your model capturing reality completely.

Comment: @Theraot Thank you for answering.  problem is simplified here, the GPU is turned off, and all operations are in memory, and disk reading is not involved. Only the approximate execution time of the CPU is estimated, and the complexity of the program is already known during the test.

Comment: In that case, the first approximation is that memory size does not matter. You might want to look at cache size and memory access time instead. How much core matter depends on how well the tasks parallelizes. You can do science to that. Call your metric an hypothesis, experiment (run tests), tweak the hypothesis to match results, repeat.

Comment: @Theraot  Thank you, I have thought about calculating by the number of instructions before, hoping to get an approximate execution time (for example, in seconds, allow for errors, as long as it is not particularly large), but if the two machines are heterogeneous ( Arm and x86, the instruction sets of the two are different, it seems that they cannot be compared). I don't know if there are other methods (except to execute the program on the machine).

Comment: If you are compiling the same software for different architectures, then you also need to consider that the compiler might be better at optimizing the code for one machine than the other. If a programmer is writing a form of assembly for each machine by hand, then there is how good that programmer is with each machine code. And of course, in practice, there might be other considerations, such as the OS scheduler, other applications running at the same time, or even if the CPU has an energy saving mode. I'm unaware of any model that would give you a general good prediction of performance.

Comment: On the flip side, the performance of an application is likely to be dominated by a single aspect. There will be something that takes the most time on a task, and improving that will give you the greater boost of performance. Thus, if you know that your task does a lot of a particular kind of computation, or expends a lot of time in I/O operations, or whatever, that will tell you what metric will matter most, for that task in particular.

Comment: @Theraot Thank you.  At the beginning, my idea was to predict by cpu computing power or instructions. But if it is through instructions, it will be very complicated under heterogeneous CPUs. Then if it passes the theoretical peak, as you said before, the number of CPUs actually executed is related to the concurrency of the program.

Comment: @Theraot  Therefore, I don’t know how to predict the execution time of a known program on different machines (here only need to get the approximate execution time, only consider the cpu and memory, if the memory is very complex, you can set the memory to infinite Guarantee not to use virtual memory) Can you help me?

Comment: Please don't post the exact same question to software engineering after it is closed on stackoverflow as opinion based: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64708132/1937198 the question is not any more answerable here.

Answer (score 1):

The computing power gap between different CPUs is highly dependent on what’s being computed.

That’s why today we solve this problem with benchmarking software.   But each benchmark has the computer solve a different problem.

Back in the day clock speed was the primary feature that people used to compare CPUs. But even back then you had to decide if you needed a math coprocessor or how big the on board cache should be.

So all this is to say: it depends, what are you doing with it?